# Docker 1.10 access a container by its hostname from a host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have the Docker version 1.10 with embedded DNS service.

I have created two service containers in my docker-compose file. They are reachable each other by hostname and by IP, but when I would like reach one of them from the host machine, it doesn't work, it works only with IP but not with hostname.

So, is it possible to access a docker container from the host machine by it's hostname in the Docker 1.10, please?

**Update:**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    service_a:
        image: nginx
        container_name: docker_a
        ports:
           - 8080:80
    service_b:
        image: nginx
        container_name: docker_b
        ports:
            - 8081:80
```

then I start it by command: `docker-compose up --force-recreate`

when I run:

- `docker exec -i -t docker_a ping -c4 docker_b` - it works
- `docker exec -i -t docker_b ping -c4 docker_a` - it works
- `ping 172.19.0.2` - it works (`172.19.0.2` is `docker_b`'s ip)
- `ping docker_a` - **fails**

The result of the `docker network inspect test_default` is

```
[
    {
        "Name": "test_default",
        "Id":   "f6436ef4a2cd4c09ffdee82b0d0b47f96dd5aee3e1bde068376dd26f81e79712",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {
             "a9f13f023761123115fcb2b454d3fd21666b8e1e0637f134026c44a7a84f1b0b": {
                "Name": "docker_a",
                "EndpointID":     "a5c8e08feda96d0de8f7c6203f2707dd3f9f6c3a64666126055b16a3908fafed",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
                "c6532af99f691659b452c1cbf1693731a75cdfab9ea50428d9c99dd09c3e9a40": {
                "Name": "docker_b",
                "EndpointID":     "28a1877a0fdbaeb8d33a290e5a5768edc737d069d23ef9bbcc1d64cfe5fbe312",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: can you elaborate? what commands do you use, and what output do you get?

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for it. 

docker-compose.yml

Comment: You might need to manually add it to your hosts file

Comment: @warmoverflow: Yes, it's possible to do it this way,  but IP addresses are assigned dynamically to containers. Than is necessary to update the hosts file manually for each change :-(. So I would like to ask if is it possible to solve it without modification of the hosts file or using an extra discovery service?

Comment: I searched around and it does not seem possible without third party tool or some scripts. Why do you need to access containers directly from host without any port mapping?

Comment: @warmoverflow:  I don't need it for production, but for development. I need it for debugging and dev tools integration.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this yet.

Comment: what's docker host environment ? since it needs to be accessed from host, it needs extra service in host.  If you container name is "google.com", how do you manage to differ the real ? It needs to co-exist your host system.

Answer (score 16):

As [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071126/2979435) there is a software solution for this, called DNS Proxy Server.

```
$ sudo ./dns-proxy-server

$ docker run --rm --hostname nginx.dev nginx
$ ping nginx.dev
PING nginx.dev (172.17.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4 (172.17.0.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4 (172.17.0.4): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
```

Comment: It does not work unless I create the container with --hostname. I don't wish modify the setup of running containers. It should work with default hostname i.e container name like it does from inside containers. Is there a way?

Answer (score 15):

To specifically solve this problem I created a simple "etc/hosts" domain injection [tool](https://github.com/dvddarias/docker-hoster) that resolves names of local Docker containers on the host. Just run:

```
docker run -d \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
    -v /etc/hosts:/tmp/hosts \
    --name docker-hoster \
    dvdarias/docker-hoster
```

You will be able to access a container using the `container name`, `hostname`, `container id` and vía the `network aliases` they have declared for each network.

Containers are automatically registered when they start and removed when they are paused, dead or stopped.

Comment: Excellent product! It would be nice if it were a rootless container though, and just used docker-socket-proxy to access the socket API (or if the script ran on docker-socket-proxy itself).

Answer (score 13):

Here's what I do.

I wrote a Python script called [dnsthing](https://github.com/larsks/dnsthing/), which listens to the Docker events API for containers starting or stopping.  It maintains a `hosts`-style file with the names and addresses of containers.  Containers are named `<container_name>.<network>.docker`, so for example if I run this:

```
docker run --rm --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret  mysql
```

I get this:

```
172.17.0.2 mysql.bridge.docker
```

I then run a `dnsmasq` process pointing at this `hosts` file.  Specifically, I run a dnsmasq instance using the following configuration:

```
listen-address=172.31.255.253
bind-interfaces
addn-hosts=/run/dnsmasq/docker.hosts
local=/docker/
no-hosts
no-resolv
```

And I run the `dnsthing` script like this:

```
dnsthing -c "systemctl restart dnsmasq_docker" \
  -H /run/dnsmasq/docker.hosts --verbose
```

So:

- `dnsthing` updates `/run/dnsmasq/docker.hosts` as containers
  stop/start
- After an update, `dnsthing` runs `systemctl restart dnsmasq_docker`
- `dnsmasq_docker` runs `dnsmasq` using the above configuration, bound
  to a local bridge interface with the address `172.31.255.253`.
- The "main" dnsmasq process on my system, maintained by
  NetworkManager, uses this configuration from
  `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dockerdns`:

  ```
  server=/docker/172.31.255.253
  ```

  That tells dnsmasq to pass all requests for hosts in the `.docker`
  domain to the `docker_dnsmasq` service.

This obviously requires a bit of setup to put everything together, but
after that it seems to Just Work:

```
$ ping -c1  mysql.bridge.docker
PING mysql.bridge.docker (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms

--- mysql.bridge.docker ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.087/0.087/0.087/0.000 ms
```

Comment: This looks pretty interesting, thanks, but there are some holes in my understanding... where does the `dnsmasq_docker` thing come in?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to add entries to your hosts file

- for linux: add `127.0.0.1 docker_a docker_b` to /etc/hosts file
- for mac: similar to linux but use ip of virtual machine `docker-machine ip default`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @larsks, I wrote a Python script too but implemented it as service. Here it is: https://github.com/nicolai-budico/dockerhosts

It launches dnsmasq with parameter `--hostsdir=/var/run/docker-hosts` and updates file `/var/run/docker-hosts/hosts` each time a list of running containers was changed.
Once file `/var/run/docker-hosts/hosts` is changed, dnsmasq automatically updates its mapping and container become available by hostname in a second.

```
$ docker run -d --hostname=myapp.local.com --rm -it ubuntu:17.10
9af0b6a89feee747151007214b4e24b8ec7c9b2858badff6d584110bed45b740

$ nslookup myapp.local.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   myapp.local.com
Address: 172.17.0.2
```

There are install and uninstall scripts. Only you need is to allow your system to interact with this dnsmasq instance. I registered in in systemd-resolved:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.54
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=yes
#MulticastDNS=yes
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=udp
```