# Access to docker container using host name instead of localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose and docker. everything works great. but the only way to access a service from the host machine is by http://localhost:port. i would like to be able to access by using the container name like: http://elastic:9020.

It works well inside the docker. if one container needs to access another i can use the http://elastic:9020 but not from the Host. Of Course that i am exposing the ports and using port mapping and it works using localhost as i said. Docker

**UPDATE:** I was looking for a native solution without the needs of installing DNS Server or updating the .host file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access docker container from host using containers name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242217/access-docker-container-from-host-using-containers-name)

Answer (score 3):

There is an OSS project aimed for resolving Docker's hostnames:

[DPS :: DNS Proxy Server](http://mageddo.github.io/dns-proxy-server/latest/en/)

DPS is a end user(developers, Server Administrators) DNS server tool to develop systems with docker solving docker containers hostnames.

Github repo: [mageddo/dns-proxy-server](https://github.com/mageddo/dns-proxy-server)

Main features:

> - Solve hostnames from local configuration database
> - Solve hostnames from docker containers using docker **hostname** option or **HOSTNAMES** env
> - Solve hostnames from a list of configured DNS servers(as a proxy) if no answer of two above
> - Solve hostnames using wildcards
> - Graphic interface to Create/List/Update/Delete **A/CNAME** records
> - Solve host machine IP using `host.docker` hostname
> - Access container by it’s container name / service name
> - Specify from which network solve container IP

Usage:

`docker run --rm --hostname dns.mageddo \ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ -v /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf \ defreitas/dns-proxy-server`

Comment: So i understand that there is no native solution for that ?

Comment: I wish there was an easy answer... However you slice it, you need to modify or replace how your DNS server handles and parses Docker containers. I got this tool running on a CentOS 8 VM instance with multiple Docker containers running different cross-dependent SaaSs (Spring Boot apps, Keycloak, etc) and it worked basically out-of-the-box. That being said, I would LOVE to see documentation on how this would work (or a good solution on how to make addressing work in general) in a production environment like AWS.

Comment: AWS has it's own DNS: `Route 53`