# php artisan command shows Redis error when running locally instead of inside Docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, redis, containers

I am using Laravel + Docker and I have a container for Redis. But when I run locally `php artisan list` then I get this error. I want to run this command locally (not in container), I already did `composer install` locally.

*The reason I want to do this on my local machine is so that I could run other artisan commands on my machine (like create a new controller or model). It also helps with intelisense.*

```
$ php artisan list

Predis\Connection\ConnectionException 
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. [tcp://myapp-redis-server:6379]
```

If I change it to localhost, I get a different error `REDIS_HOST=localhost`

```
$ php artisan list

Predis\Connection\ConnectionException 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://localhost:6379]
```

Comment: There are not much details. Apparently, your Docker doesn't forward Redis port from external to internal. Can you share output of these commands: `docker ps` and `netstat -tpln`

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242217/access-docker-container-from-host-using-containers-name helps.

Comment: I guess I didn't need to run it locally after all, I could run them all through a container and it worked `docker exec -it app-php-server php artisan list`