# Kafka container connecting from inside the container and outside using the same hostname

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am aware this topic has several questions and blog posts about it. I am following these two:
https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
But unfortunately, without success.
I'm trying to make it so the same code will work whether I'm running it from my IDE where the kafka client is in a container, or whether the code I'm running is in a container within the network. I am able to make each scenario work on its own, but not the two together.
My docker compose:

```
  zoo1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.2.1
    hostname: zoo1
    container_name: zoo1
    ports:
     - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.1
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
```

In this docker-compose, communication within the docker network using `kafka1:29092` as bootstrap works great. but, from my laptop using the same doesn't work.
Is there anyway to ensure that both locally and inside the container network I can bootstrap to `kafka1:29092`? Do I even need the external listener?
Thanks

Comment: We need to distinguish between internal and external connections since the actual kafka hosts are accessible through different names (`kafka1:29092` internally, `localhost:9092` externally). Thus, the address to the bootstrap server must be different, depending on the runtime environment (internally vs. externally). And yes, we need the internal and external mapping for this to work.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks, but shouldn't the port mapping make it possible for me to communicate using `kafka1:29092` even from my IDE? is there any way to achieve my desired functionality (that isn't a hack)?

Comment: The initial connection isn't the problem; the advertised listener to connect to the kafka-cluster is (internally, it must resolve to `kafka1`, externally it must resolve to `localhost`). And yes there is. You have it right there. [I do something very similar in my local setup(`bitbucket.org`)](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/uber-docker-compose/src/73909d6f52a9f6edb357183b867e64bf2931812d/localdeployment/docker-compose.yml#lines-83).

Comment: Thanks for your reference, I'll take a look. My intention was - no way to bootstrap to the same address both internally and externally? I'll have to change to `localhost:9092` on my IDE?

Comment: I would suggest to [externalize (`12factors.net`)](https://12factor.net/config) the connection to the kafka bootstrap server, defaulting to whatever you need it to be in your IDE, and then override it through an environment variable in the docker deployment.

Comment: Maybe this can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828487/docker-1-10-access-a-container-by-its-hostname-from-a-host-machine

If you are using Linux, you can also use --network=host, then access your kafka container with `localhost:29092` from inside and outside of the docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> anyway to ensure that both locally and inside the container network I can bootstrap to kafka1:29092?

No.

Your host isn't aware of the DNS / service names used by Docker.

Instead, add an environment variable in your code like `KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS`, then set that as a variable in your IDE (as **`localhost:9092`**) via a run config, or as a container variable (`kafka1:29092`)

You can also remove `- "29092:29092"` from your compose file since your host will never need that port to connect with the broker